# Extract subclass from class using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with the following HTML snippet from a page on Goodreads using Python 3.6.3:

```
<div class="quoteText">
      “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”
  <br/>  ―
    <a class="authorOrTitle" href="/author/show/61105.Dr_Seuss">Dr. Seuss</a>
</div>, <div class="quoteText">
```

I used BeautifulSoup to scrape the HTML and isolate just the "quoteText" class seen in the snippet above. Now, I want to save the quote and author name as separate strings. I was able to get the author name using

```
(quote_tag.find(class_="quoteText")).text
```

I'm not sure how to do the same for the quote. I'm guessing I need a way to remove the  subclass from my output and tried using the extract method.

```
quote.extract(class_="authorOrTitle")
```

but I got an error saying extract got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_'
Is there any other way to do what I'm trying to do?

This is my first time posting on here so I apologize if the post doesn't meet particular specificity/formatting/other standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PageElement.extract() removes a tag or string from the tree. It
>   returns the tag or string that was extracted

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
a='''<div class="quoteText">
      “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”
  <br/>  -
    <a class="authorOrTitle" href="/author/show/61105.Dr_Seuss">Dr. Seuss</a>
</div>, <div class="quoteText">'''
s=BeautifulSoup(a,'lxml')
s.find(class_="authorOrTitle").extract()
print(s.text)
```